# Number of predictions in each run must be equal to the number of labels for each run

Tags: r

I am trying to detect the  best `AUC` using `genetic algorithm` in `R`. Here is the code:

```
library(GA)
library(ROCR)
realResult <- sample( c(T,F), 350, replace=TRUE, prob=c( 0.5, 0.5) )
AUCfitness<-function(scores){
  res<-prediction(scores, realResult, label.ordering = NULL)
  auc.tmp <- performance(res,"auc"); 
  auc <- as.numeric(auc.tmp@y.values)
  #  print(paste0("AUC is: ",auc))
  auc
}

min <- 0.000654226
max <- 9433.873
GA <- ga(type = "real-valued", fitness = AUCfitness, min = min, max = max, monitor = FALSE,popSize = 350)
summary(GA)
```

But in line `ga` it complains with :

```
 Error in prediction(scores, realResult, label.ordering = NULL) : 
  Number of predictions in each run must be equal to the number of labels for each run.
```

As you see, I have the size of `realResult` as 350 and `popSize = 350`, so i shouldn't face with this error

Comment: How come you didn't get an answer to this question? I now have the same problem and a solution would be very helpful.

Comment: Have the same problem and tried so many ways. Still can't figure out the problem

Answer (score 0):

Got this problem a few minutes ago. 
Seems like all because of NA.
I deleted all NA cases related with the model, then everything works fine.